# Generate HTML tags using JSON and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have the following JSON schema

```
{
"employee":
             {"display_name":"EMPLOYEE NAME:",
              "format":"string",
              "type":"textbox",
              "dflt":"null",
              "isMandatory":"true"}
}
```

Now I have to generate an html tag i.e

```
<input type="text" value="name"></input>
```

How do I use the JSON with jQuery? I know I have to use append method. But I'm not sure how to append JSON elements.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, do you have multiple 'employees'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse your text into a JSON object.  Then use jQuery to create any elements you want and append it where you want. (Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/x8dY7/7/))

```
 var myJSON = '{ "employee": { "display_name":"EMPLOYEE NAME:", "format":"string", "type":"textbox", "dflt":"null", "isMandatory":"true" } }';

 var employee = $.parseJSON(myJSON).employee; //get employee object
 if (employee.type == "textbox") {
   $('<label>').attr({for: 'employee_name'}).text(employee.display_name).appendTo($('body'));
   $('<input>').attr({type: 'text', id:'employee_name'}).appendTo($('body'));
 }
```

This generates the HTML:

```
 <label for="employee_name">EMPLOYEE NAME:</label>
 <input type="text" id="employee_name">
```

I'm sure this is not exactly what you want, but this should definitely lead you in the right direction to solving your problem.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for: http://neyeon.com/p/jquery.dform/doc/files2/readme-txt.html